# Facing an issue after running “netsh wlan show profiles” command

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, netsh

I want to retrieve password of an old WiFi connection but when I run `netsh wlan show profile command it shows:
[image]

what should I do?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to give you the password.  What sort of security would that be.

Comment: @RohitGupta Incorrect, see my answer in the duplicate.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks